# Person who has had a program hard wired into their daily routine

Tags: adjectives

What is the best word to describe a person that has done the same thing contractually for a long period of time, to the point in which they still carry out these tasks without being specifically contracted to do so?

For example, an army recruit waking up every day at the crack of dawn to go for a run or exercise even after their service is through.

Comment: He's been conditioned to do that; or he's running on autopilot (for when the car drives itself to work, even on your day off).

Comment: those are correct in a sense but I mean to directly describe the person as a  "conditioned" person... a different synonym to encorprate the fact that it is through contractual circumstances... almost forced but not as intrusive haha... is conditioned the best word? or compulsive maybe?

Comment: The activity is "habitual" and "ingrained".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *[automaton](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/automaton)* might suit

> a person who acts in a mechanical or machinelike way

*Merriam-Webster*

Note that this term often has a slightly pejorative tone and is often used to convey lack of emotion as much as routine behavior.

Comment: :O brilliant answer! I like that. It would bode well in creative writing...

Answer (score 2):

"Force of habit" seems to be the most general way to state it.

```
behavior made involuntary or automatic by repeated practice
```

[Merriam Webster link](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/force%20of%20habit)

As you mentioned in the comments, "conditioned" hits close to the same description, but to me it seems to imply it was done specifically to instill those habits. "Force of habit" does not carry the same implications.

Comment: *Force of habit* does not specifically  refer to a habit acquired from you job or profession.

Comment: Force of Habit is the way in which the condition came about but I want to know if there is another word to replace "conditioned person" in the comment example above...

Comment: @Josh61 I don't see OP remarking it had to specifically pertain to a profession. OP's use of "contractually" doesn't conclusively mean it's to do with employment either.

Answer (score 0):

**Conditioned** (like Pavlov's dog)?

Comment: Does that not imply the repetitive behavior was "forced" with the intent of making it a habit? From my interpretation of OP's question, it should also be possible that the habit wasn't the initial goal of the repetitive task, but an unrelated consequence.

Comment: Yes, it does. So it's not a perfect solution. But "force of habit" isn't perfect either, as OP wanted a word for the _person_. For that reason i wonder now about "habituated".

Comment: I was thinking about the exact same word :) Although it seems correct, it does sound a bit odd to me though.

Comment: Habituated is almost there... an answer appeared but mustve been deleted which suggested the person was a "Behavioural Addict" or a person who had developed "Behavioural Addiction"