# What's the term for only doing something because you've been doing it a long time even though you may not enjoy the activity anymore?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for only doing something because you've been doing it a long time, even though you may not enjoy the activity anymore?

Comment: Carrying on with it _from force of habit_?

Comment: It has become part of my routine.

Comment: There are several other questions and answers that already cover this in general. But it's not clear if you're looking for something that's specific to a lack of enjoyment. Is the activity something that you're forced to do (like work), or something that you simply do because you're used to it? Please provide an example or two with detailed context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [person who has had a program hard-wired into their daily routine](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241975/person-who-has-had-a-program-hard-wired-into-their-daily-routine/241976#241976) Answers include 'force of habit', 'automaton', the practice being 'mechanical' / 'machinelike'.

Comment: Dear Glenn: to ensure that your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Click on "Info" or "View Tag" and "Learn more ..." for more information. Sincerely, me.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a **rut** to me. From Lexico:

> **[rut](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/rut)**: A habit or pattern of behavior that has become dull and unproductive but is hard to change.

Example:

> I've been *in a rut* (or *stuck in a rut* or *caught in a rut*) for the last ten years, but I can't figure out how to get out of it. My situation's driving me insane.

Comment: Yes, 'Caught in a rut' would be the idiom.

Comment: @GoodJuJu Thanks. Yes. Definitely.

Comment: @GoodJuJu And “Stuck in a rut,” which is more common, at least in the U.S.